# CodeIgniter issues

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

1) **I wanted to get rid of the bootstrap (index.php) name in the URL.** I've been in YouTube searching and downloading lots of videos related to this, but none of them worked. This is the .htaccess file:

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !=d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried everything I could get on the Internet.

2) **I couldn't load the files in the `public` folder where I store my JavaScript, CSS and image files.** Path: `codeigniter/application/`.

What I tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_URL() ?>public/css/default.css />
```

And the same for JavaScript files.

3) **Routing problems(confusion)**. My default route us the dashboard controller. But I also wanted to create a login route. So I did this:

```
$route['login'] = 'login';
```

But this still routes to the default route when I go to `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/login`.

Answer (score 1):

Try these `.htaccess`

```
# -FrontPage-    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: may there be other factors for this?

Comment: @mzcoxfde check rewrite rule in on and check the base url and index is define corectly.

Comment: Did you tried adding a RewriteBase to your projet folder from root?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `.htaccess` file and also remove `index.php` from your `config.php` file e.g. `$config['index_page'] = '';`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```